# How to update rails code for CollectionProxy after upgrade from 3.2 to 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this code that was working on `Rails 3.2`

```
arg = Project.first.tasks
return arg.map{|l| identifier_for l } if arg.kind_of? Array
```

Now as in `Rails 4` it returns a `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Tasks` and not an `Array` the `if` doesn't works.

What is the right way to update this piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the solution I am proposing, as I don't know about you complete code, but I think this `if` you have here to check, whether you have got the results in `arg` or not. You can do this in following way as well:-

```
arg = Project.first.tasks
return arg.map{|l| identifier_for l } unless arg.blank?
```

Answer (score 0):

What i did is:

```
if arg.kind_of?(ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy)
  return arg.map{|l| identifier_for l }
end
```

Could please anyone confirm if this is the right approach?